# Pass a View Data From Controller to Ajax View File - Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

From View Page I am calling Ajax to my Controller, from my Controller I want to create a html data so I am passing my array to View file to create a HTML data.
I don't know why when I try to do console nothing gets return, can anyone tell me where I am going wrong

**CallingAjaxFromViewFile**

```
function AjaxgetCheckInChekOutUser(status){
    var url = "{{ url('admin/events/ajaxData') }}";
    var token = $('#token').val();
    if(status){
        $.ajax({
                headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'status': status,'_token':token},            
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    data = JSON.parse(data);      
                        console.log(data.html);
                        $('#gymimages').html(data.html);
                    
                }
        });
    }
}
```

**myControllerFile**

```
public function AjaxCurrentPastFutureData($data, $status){
    $title = "HDTuto.com";  

    $html = view('admin.events.ajaxdataview')->with(compact('title'))->render();
    //pr($html);
    $response = response()->json(['success' => true, 'html' => $html]);
    return $response;
}
```

**NowmyViewFile** From Where I append HTML Data

```
<h1><i>{{ $title }} </i></h1>
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: What are you getting in your request? check in your network XHR request. This way you'll know what you're passing and what response you're getting

Comment: When I am pr($data); it is printing bt only thing is not returning

Answer (score 4):

** Use this**

```
function AjaxgetCheckInChekOutUser(status){
var url = "{{ url('admin/events/ajaxData') }}";
var token = $('#token').val();
if(status){
    $.ajax({                
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'status': status,'_token':token},            
            success: function (data) {                    
                    $('#gymimages').html(data.html);
            }
    });
```

**Also update your Controller function**

```
public function AjaxCurrentPastFutureData(Request $request){
    $title = "HDTuto.com";  
    $html = view('my')->with(compact('title'))->render();
    //pr($html);
    $response = response()->json(['success' => true, 'html' => $html]);
    return $response;
```

}

Comment: Thank you this solved my issue I was doing it all wrong first but then followed your code and everything is working fine Thank you so much you saved my day